# Running chargino/neutralino masses in MSSM

Tags: particle-physics, renormalization, mssm

Consider the plot below, showing the running of different masses due to renormalization for a certain point of the (c)MSSM. I am able to exactly reproduce the plot, including the running of M1, M2, M3. However, I can't get the running values of the actual particle masses (e.g. $m(\chi^0_1)$) from the generators. I tried SoftSusy and SPheno, and in both cases the parameters shown below are calculated at the supplied scale, given in the MSOFT block of the SLHA output. The particle masses are given in the MASS block, and are independent of the scale.

This is a bit confusing. I was under the impression that M1, M2, M3, ... are high-scale parameters - variables that you put into the theory at the GUT scale, and only make sense there. After all, you don't have the photino, wino, etc. as real physical mass eigenstates, you only have the mixtures. OTOH, particle masses should make sense at many scales. If you probe e.g. the $\chi^\pm_2$ at different scales of momentum transfer $Q$, you should get different masses.

This plot, and the output of the spectrum generators, seem to imply the opposite: That the particle masses don't run, but that a running $M_i$ is meaningful.

What's the truth? Is there a generator that can give me the running values of $m(\chi^0_1)$ etc.? Can I easily calculate them myself from the running $M_i$ and the mixing angles? What I'd like to make is a plot that shows the actual particle masses run, and eventually unify at the GUT scale to $m_{1/2}$ (or $M_i^\mathrm{GUT}$ in the non-universal case).

[image]

mSUGRA: $m_0=100, m_{12}=250, \tan\beta=10, A_0=-100, \,\mathrm{sign}\,\mu=+1$,
Taken from https://softsusy.hepforge.org/

Comment: Physical masses are scale independent. Lagrangian parameters are in general unphysical and run with scale, though might coincide with physical parameters in e.g. Onshell scheme.

Comment: If you are interested in residual dependence of physical masses on renormalisation scale, allanach et al published a few papers

Comment: @innisfree I'm aware that *pole* masses are scale independent (what one might call the "physical" mass). What I'm interested in is the running mass. Probe a particle in low- and high-energy interactions, and you will see a different apparent mass due to screening effects/quantum corrections, right? $m(\tilde g)(Q) = M_3$, since gluinos don't mix. I'm interested in $m(\tilde\chi^\pm_i)(Q)$, if that makes sense. I am not really interested in the effect of the renormalization scale choice (what one might sloppily call cutoff scale) on the pole masses, which is more of a computational effect.